# How to pass name attribute dynamically in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages partial tag helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, tag-helpers

I know I can reuse UI elements using [`<partial>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0) tag helper.

For example, I can create a `TextBox` and reuse it this way:

```
<partial name="MyTextBox" model='new TextBoxModel { Label = "my lable" }' />
```

However, I need to be able to pass the name of the text box dynamically.

```
<partial name="FieldComponents.TextBoxComponent" />
```

I can't make it work. using `@Html.Partial` I could do it, and since `<partial>` tag is here to replace old HTML helpers, I expect it to support that.

How can I pass the name dynamically to `<partial>` tag in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Answer (score 2):

You pass an expression that renders a string:

```
<partial name="@(DateTime.Now.Second %2 == 0 ? "_A" : "_B")"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo:
Model:

```
public class FieldComponents
    {
        public string TextBoxComponent { get; set; }
    }
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
        public FieldComponents FieldComponents { get; set; } = new FieldComponents();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            FieldComponents.TextBoxComponent = "Partial1";
        }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemo.Pages.Test.IndexModel
<partial name="@Model.FieldComponents.TextBoxComponent" />
```

Partial1:

```
<h1>Partial1</h1>
```

result:
[image]